# Clone a git repository all the way back to a specific commit, but not everything

Tags: git

Let's take the [Linux Kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git) as an example.
Let's say we want to have a local copy, but are only interested in its recent history, and since this repo has a huge history, we want to do a shallow clone so that git operations work faster (it won't have to parse the whole history every time, only what we have locally).

OK, let's figure out how far back we need to fetch. Say `v4.0` is as far back as we want, how do we convert that to a `--depth`?

```
$ git rev-list --count v4.0..torvalds/master
95302
```

So there have been 95302 commits on master since `v4.0`, that sounds like it should be the correct depth, right?  Let's try:

```
$ git clone --depth=95302 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
Cloning into 'linux'...
remote: Counting objects: 4791958, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3558/3558), done.
remote: Total 4791958 (delta 2188), reused 640 (delta 174), pack-reused 4788216
Receiving objects: 100% (4791958/4791958), 1.49 GiB | 12.93 MiB/s, done.
```

That looks like a lot has been fetched. Let's see how far back it goes:

```
$ git -C linux tag | head
v2.6.12
v2.6.12-rc2
v2.6.12-rc3
v2.6.12-rc4
v2.6.12-rc5
v2.6.12-rc6
v2.6.13
v2.6.13-rc1
v2.6.13-rc2
v2.6.13-rc3
```

OK, we obviously fetched waaay too much here.

**How can I figure out how much to fetch, ie. what `--depth` to request?**

*Edit:* to be clear, the goal is to have the history between some old commit and now (bonus point if it allows to fetch new commits after that, like a shallow clone does).
Answers that destroy the history (like the one given so far) obviously don't satisfy this.

I just found out about `git-replace` which might be able to graft a squashed version of the history before the commit we want. I'll give that a go, and update this question/answer it depending on the outcome.

Comment: You can't in general without already having a clone, so it's kind of silly, but: you need to count *depth* rather than *commits* (the latter includes breadth: simple example, suppose tip of branch X is a merge and you need to go 2 commits back to reach your goal, following either X^ to X^^ or X^2 to X^^; `rev-list --count` would count 3, except for a fencepost error due to lack of `--boundary`). `--first-parent` won't always work either but is a start, as is `--ancestry-path`. Also you probably want `--single-branch` on the clone step.

Comment: @torek, `--single-branch` is implied in `--depth`.

Comment: @AnoE: Oh, I see, so it does!  Thanks.

Comment: "we want to do a shallow clone so that [...] it won't have to parse the whole history every time" . . .  what, specifically and concretely, what operations are you talking about?

Comment: @jthill: as far as I can tell, all the git operations work with a shallow clone (as long as you don't try to access stuff before the first commit). This includes at least these that I use daily (off the top of my head): log, diff, commit, push, fetch, pull, rebase, format-patch, am, rev-parse/-list, branch, checkout, and reset.

Comment: Which of those, in your experience, lead git to "parse the whole history"?

Comment: `log` obviously, which I use most, as well as `rev-parse`/`rev-list` which I use much less. `checkout` and `reset` might parse a lot too, but I rarely use them to go far back.  To give some context, my dayjob includes watching what happens (mailing lists) on a few Kernel subsystems and other projects (Mesa, X, Wayland, etc.), and tracking everything we missed by digging in the repositories. Being able to have a local repo for only the 2-3 latest releases, then one for the 5-10 latest releases, etc. would allow for much faster code archeology when you know approximately how long ago it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I believe git does not offer a way to clone back to exactly one given commit. At least `rev-list` does not seem to have enough options to output a count compatible with `--depth`.

You can do it with `git clone --depth` though, in a fashion (note with respect to the comment: I assume the whole excercise is intended to avoid cruft in your final repository, and that you are *not* having trouble with the initial full download, i.e. the network usage is no problem for you, and you have enough HDD space to hold the larger repository temporarily):

```
git clone --depth=95302 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git linux-95k

git clone --depth=10000 file://`pwd`/linux-95k linux

# oops, too little!

rm -rf linux
git clone --depth=50000 file://`pwd`/linux-95k linux

# oops, still too much!

...
```

That is, binary searching with a little human heuristics.... It should not take too many tries and could be scripted.

EDIT: changed the answer so it only downloads over the network once.

Comment: "It should not take too many tries (on the order of 10-15 or so)" → I can't tell if you're trolling, but just in case you're not: the Linux Kernel has a bit more than 2¹⁰–2¹⁵ (1k–32k) commits. Currently there are 602598 commits on `master`, and doing such a clone would download about 1GB on average (0­–1.6GB) each time, so your solution would not only be the most inefficient I could think of and waste huge amounts of bandwidth, but also take days to run.

Comment: I am not trolling. We are not talking 602598 commits, the poster already found an upper limit of 95000 commits. `log2(95000)=17`, which will be the upper limit for binary search. He can avoid the repeated downloads by cloning a local clone. And, with due respect, even the 120MB of a `--depth=1` clone of the linux kernel is a tiny amount of data compared to the vast amount of data streamed by Youtube & Co every day! I assume he will not be doing this operation (of finding the correct --depth) from scratch more than once, of course.

Comment: OK, I apologize, I shouldn't have replied the way I did. Yes, local clones will be faster and less wasteful than getting them from the network, but this brute force technique doesn't really look good. And the `v4.0` example was just that, an example, the actual value will vary (on the larger side).  Not sure I understand your point about other things being bigger, though. Anyway, I upvoted your answer as it does answer the question, albeit not the best way (which is subjective). I will still look into `git-replace` when I get some time (not today). Sorry for being a bit of an ass earlier :(

Answer (score 0):

> we are only interested in its recent history ... how do we convert that to a --depth

You cant do it unless you have a full clone and then chap off the unrequired data.

To do it you have few ways:

1. clone the whole repo, then create a orphan branch and cherry pick all the commits from the desired point to the end.
2. similar to the above:

   ```
   git clone --branch <tag_name> <repo_url>
   # or 
   git checkout tags/<tag_name>
   ```
3. `clone` and then perform a `reset --hard` to the desired point + `squash` to combine all the commits to a single commit.

Comment: So your answer is "I don't have an answer, but you can do these other things"?  To reply to your suggestions: (1) and (3) would lose the history, voiding the whole point of trying to have said history in the first place, and (2) doesn't satisfy anything from the question. I'll edit the question to make it clear that losing the history is counter-productive.